# Performing custom actions on `scons -c`

Tags: python, makefile, scons

I have made a SCons builder that takes a `Makefile` file as a source and calls it to generate "things".

(Mainly it is a Makefile written by other libraries, so I don't have to choice to replace it with SCons).

So far, it works well but now I'd like to make the `scons -c` work as well.

My `MakefileCallBuilder` only has a dummy target as its target so `scons -c` won't really clean anything.

Is there a way of telling SCons that I want `make clean` or `make distclean` to be called upon cleaning ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been pulling my hair out because of this exact problem. I finally created a solution that is kind of crude, but works. Here is the part of the SConstruct file which does cleaning:

```
import subprocess

...

# Call make to clean
if env.GetOption('clean'):
    subprocess.call(['make', 'clean'])
```

Basically, since Scons does not offer any way to call `make clean`, I get it done via Python's subprocess.call().